# How to prepare a qubit into a particular superposition state?

Tags: quantum-information

Given sufficient number of qubits starting in $|0\rangle$ states, and number of operations of universal gates, how to prepare a qubit of a specific state? A state such as

$ \frac{3}{5} |0\rangle + \frac{4}{5} |1\rangle$

Comment: You have to tell us which gate set your using. Also do you want exactly that state or a convergent sequence of approximations? Like it is easier to produce linear combinations using powers of $2$ in the denominators using some gate sets.

Comment: Was thinking of the typical gates, X,Z,H,CNOT or Toffoli gate, and a good approximation will do.

Answer (score 2):

Using only the $X, Y, Z$ and $H$ gates you can only move along the 6 poles of the Bloch sphere. To reach an arbitrary point on the sphere, that is an arbitrary state, you need smaller rotations.

Take a look at this: [Universal quantum gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Universal_quantum_gates)

You may also find useful [this simulator](http://algassert.com/quirk)

Comment: Thanks. Can it be achieved by having more Qubits and double-Qubit gates?

Comment: @Wang-X-Y Same thing, you need to use smaller rotations. The CNOT is a control-X, and the Toffoli is a control-control-X. They only perform  $\pi$ or $\pi/2$ overall rotations around the xyz axes. To reach arbitrary points you need smaller rotations. In real life you will have this smaller rotations. If you have some physical process that acts on your qubit as a $\pi/2$ rotation along the x-axis, it is in general possible to make that process act for less time to achieve a smaller rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Suppose we choose a three-qubit system $|000\rangle$. First we pass the first and the second qubit through H gate, then we do a Toffoli gate with the first two as inputs and third qubit as output, does it amount to a smaller rotation on the third qubit?

Comment: Here's a [simulation](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={"cols":[["H","H"],["%E2%80%A2","%E2%80%A2","X"]]}) of what you requested: it only means that the state of the last qubit is not separable.

Comment: @Mattero You are right at this stage it's entangled, but there may be a way to isolate it downstream. The simulator is very useful, how can I add one more qubit?

Comment: @Wang-X-Y when you move something new to the circuit it will show a new qubit under the last one automatically